# How to use Addin Command in Angular2 Outlook Add-in

Tags: angular, office-js

How do I use Add-in Commands with an Angular Outlook Add-in?

We have a Office.js Add-in and have a `Functions.html` and a `Functions.js` to call command. We have added the URL for `functions.html` to our Manifest file.

- `Functions.html`: An empty HTML file to load `Functions.js` for clients that support Add-in Commands.
- `Functions.js`: The code that is invoked when the Add-in Command buttons are clicked.

Can any one suggest a way to use Add-in Commands using Angular?

Comment: Hi Sandun, have a look for the [demo](https://github.com/Hongbo-Miao/office-addin-angular) and [quick start](https://github.com/Hongbo-Miao/office-addin-quick-start/blob/master/angular.md)

Comment: @HongboMiao Thanks, I have looked your sample previously. Sample is for open a side pane. I need to know how to use Add-in command (function file) in angular.

Answer (score 6):

Command add-in does not supposed to have any UI, so it does not makes any sense to use angular 2 or any frontend framework here. The intend of command add-in is executing some code on click on the button.

If you are using task pane add-in that has UI then it makes sense to use frontend frameworks like Angular.

If you want to use Angular 2/4 in task pane then you need to boot the angular application after office is initialized.

```
 Office.initialize = function (reason) {
     //Bootstrap angular app her. 
 };
```

Comment: Yes currently I am using angular app for task pane. And for Addin command i need to access function inside ts. ( You are correct Add-in command used for execute the code). I don want to mixed with angular and JS both. I just want to write function file using .ts and call from manifest. I can find out some examples for angularJS but not in Angular.

Comment: If that is the case then you can write your code in ts file and during build the ts file will be converted to JS. you need to make sure that the function name that you provide should exists in global namespace(window object).

Comment: Are you using webapack or ng-cli to build angular app? if you are using webpak then its easy to build using webpack

Comment: I am using ng-cli.

Comment: There are lots of options of doing that, you can use webpack to do the same https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/
I would recommend not combing this with angular app, if there are not much things shared

Comment: Thanks @deepak but i need to call angular services( common functions ) from the function file .ts. I am using ng-cli to build process. And function file is in the out of the app folder. when i using ng serve or ng build it does not create a .js file for that. Do you know how to build .ts file locate outside of the app folder.

Answer (score 1):

[Add-in Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/add-in-commands-for-outlook) are specified in your [Manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/manifests) and are not concerned with which framework you're add-in was written with.

You can find a walk through in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins) under [Add-in commands for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/add-in-commands-for-outlook).

Comment: Thanks for giving information. I have defined function file in the manifest. I need to know How do i add function files(.html/js) in a angular add-in.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow where Angular is involved. These are static files physically hosted on your web server.

Comment: Do you have any resource to how to use Add-in command in Angular2 Add-in.

Comment: Again, this has nothing to do with being an Angular Add-in. Add-in Commands work the same way if you write it in Angular, Express, ASP.NET or raw JavaScript. We have tips for Angular @ https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/add-ins-with-angular2 but there isn't any special Angular instructions.

Comment: Yes - It is like physically hosted file in a server. But when Angular 2 involving i need to know how do i add function.html to call Function file.When i call component its load the entire application. and does not call the function in add-in command.